# Update value if the user is logout

Tags: laravel-5

How to update values when the user is logout from the application/web?

```
public function logout(Request $request, $user) {

 $conn = DB::select("show full processlist");

  foreach($conn as $con){
    $user->connID = null;
    $user->connDate =null;
    $user->last_login_ip = null;
    $user->update();
    $user = Auth::logout();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an event listener to the logout event.

The following link shows all the events that laravel triggers:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#events

Make your own event-listener and add it in the EventServiceprovider inside the logout-event array. Put your custom logic inside that listener to change your table.

Comment: How to logout other user? i created connection monitoring which admin can kick user. do you have any idea?

Comment: @Angol703 This might help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices

Comment: Hello @christovphvh i already read the docs but this Auth::logout(); syntax will logout the current user and not the specific user.